# Remove hyphen from value and write in text file

Tags: vbscript, adsutil.vbs

I'm reading some value from excel and writing to the text file. that's not a problem.

But in excel having value like (ex: 19631-3832-2872 ) and I want to store value in text file without hyphen like (ex: 1963138322872).

Before saving this value in text file, I need to add some constant value like (ex:1234561963138322872)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
prefix = "123456"
excelValue = "19631-3832-2872"
result = prefix  & Replace("19631-3832-2872","-","")
```

This should do it.